# Are there safe colors for android, such as web safe colors?

Tags: android, colors, web-safe-colors

Colors that I've used in my android app seems really different in different devices. So is there any color collection that is exactly same in different devices?

Do web safe colors do same work in android?

Thanks

Comment: In what views you use those colors?

Comment: Colors ARE (NOT SEEM) different on each device, since there aren't in the world 2 displays which are exactly the same.

Comment: @Yahor10. In action bar, images, progress bar and... . For example color `#F25B00` is so darker in nexus 5 than Sony Ericson.

Comment: @Funkystein You mean it is impossible to avoid that?

Comment: Of course. Small changes in microvolt due to project design or magnetic interference (not even to mention temperature!) will influence the color of the lliquid crystals even the SAME display on 2 different devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of "web-safe" colors is long outdated:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Web-safe_colors

The only reason they existed was to deal with the problem of some devices / displays not being able to display 24-bit color (0-255 red, 0-255 green, 0-255 blue).

All modern devices that you'd even care about developing anything for support 24-bit color.

Now, you will run into a different problem where the same color value (something like 0xD4D0C8) will look different on different devices and displays. There's not really anything you can do about that. Certain colors won't be more consistent than others.

Personally, I wouldn't really worry about that too much, unless you're writing an app or something that specifically deals with color matching or something similar. In that case, you'd probably want a way to calibrate the device to some standard, but I doubt that would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Web safe colors can only be important for color blindness and some assistive devices. For the vast majority of devices you should avoid web safe colors as they look amateurish and distract the viewer from your message or from looking at your images. More important is legibility of your text which derives from good contrast and color shades with enough gap to make body text, link text, and headers legible.